# How to remove sublists with lowest counts and keep the one with the highest count from the main list?

Tags: c#, list, collections, nested-lists

I have a list of sublists which is as `List<List<nodes>>`. I have stored some lists in the List of lists that now i refer to as the main list. Now i have to compare the counts of the elements in the sublists, that is lists that are stored in main list. I need to keep only that sublist which has the highest count amongst all the sublists and remove the remaining sublists. How to do that?

Comment: i have a list of sublists which is as List<List<node>> *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<List<Foo>> mainList = ...

// Find count of biggest sub-list.
int maxCount = mainList.Max(list => list.Count);

// Remove all other sub-lists.
mainlist.RemoveAll(list => list.Count != maxCount);
```

Do note that if more there are multiple sub-lists with maximum-count, all of them will be retained.

If you don't want this, you could arbitrarily choose one of them to retain:

```
if(mainlist.Count != 1)
   mainList.RemoveRange(1, mainList.Count - 1);
```

If you don't care about performance, and you don't mind reassigning the variable, you could do:

```
mainList = mainList.OrderByDescending(list => list.Count)
                   .Take(1)
                   .ToList();
```

**EDIT**:

In .NET 2.0, you could do something like:

```
public static void KeepBiggestSubList<T>(List<List<T>> mainList)
{
    if (mainList == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("mainList");

    if (mainList.Count == 0)
        return;

    List<T> maxList = mainList[0];

    foreach (List<T> list in mainList)
    {
        if (list.Count > maxList.Count)
            maxList = list;
    }

    mainList.Clear();
    mainList.Add(maxList);
}
```

Comment: No Max method comes in intellisense.

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq;` directive in your file? Also, which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: No i dont and i am working on .NET 2.0 VS 2005, Can you help by simply using comparators(< >) and Remove method?

Comment: @ghc: Ok, I will add a .NET 2.0 version.